# Почему получаю верный ответ от БД, но в вызывающем методе undefined?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, async-await

Где я допустил ошибку?

Есть метод:

```
async getUsers(req, res) {
        try {
            const result =  await db.query('SELECT * FROM users')
            console.log(result);
            res.status(200).json(result)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

Через него посылаю запрос на метод класса `DB`:

```
 async query(str){
        const connection = mysql.createConnection(DB_config)
        try{
             connection.connect()
             connection.query(str, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err
                return JSON.stringify(rows)
            });
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
        connection.end();
    }
```

В методе класса `DB`, получаю верный ответ от MySQL, но он не доходит в вызывающий метод, там просто `undefined`.

Думаю, что опять с асинхронностью наворотил, но не пойму, где точно.

Comment: Там где connection, там, наверное, await надо

Comment: У вас смешаны колбеки и промисы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно этот кейс можно решить завернув вызов `connection.query` в `Promise`:

```
async query(sql) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(DB_config)
    connection.connect((err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });

    connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows));

    connection.end();
  });
}
```

Но тут много плохих практик:

- создание коннекта на каждый запрос - плохо
- ручное заворачивание в Promise - не удобно для новичка

Используйте [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) и создавайте один коннект ([пулл коннектов](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-connection-pools)) к базе данных для всего приложения (см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1220053/2659)).

Comment: Если уж использовать промизы - в них надо заворачивать отдельные вызовы, а не алгоритм целиком.

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет тут никакого алгоритма - простое копирование простейшего usage example. Блок с кодом иллюстрирует как решить проблему, которую создал себе ТС, а после блока кода я написал как можно переработать этот код

Comment: @PavelMayorov Почему вы пишите `проми**з**ы`?

Comment: Так `async` и так обернёт в промис, зачем ещё оборачивать?

Comment: @doox911 для того чтобы управлять: дождаться результата выполнения запроса

Comment: @doox911 потому что мне не нравится как звучит вариант через "с" :-)

Comment: Спасибо. Я переделал логику используя все ваши ссылки, и вроде все получилось. Но я сделал не как у вас примере - подключение а главном файле, а сделал подключение пула в главном файле контроллера. Т.е. для всех операций контроллера одно подключение.  У меня просто их будет несколько и я не знаю как по другому передавать экземпляр подключения. 
Мое решение имеет право жить?

Comment: ваше решение существенно лучше, чем то, что вы предложили в вопросе. но вам будет лучше иметь один экземпляр "драйвера бд" для всего приложения. вынесите всю работу с mysql в отдельный модуль, выполните там createConnection, connect и в export выдавайте connect

Comment: так всё равно не нужно оборачивать в ещё один промис. Можно ж написать `await` и всё обернуть в `try/catch/finally`.

Comment: @doox911 я не очень понимаю ваше предложение. [вызов](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mysql/index.d.ts#L379) `.query` требует callback, он не возвращает promise. что вы хотите добиться await-ом? покажите код, который вы предлагаете вместо моего. и ещё одно: async обернёт возвращаемое в промис только если возвращаемое не промис, при возврате Promise никакой доп. обёртки не будет

Comment: Это по поводу [`async`](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await). Согласен и по этому не вижу смысла в возвращённом промисе. А по поводу `.query` посмотрел если [доку](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) и есть примеры с промисами. Я пытаюсь разобраться, не сочтите за упрёки.

Answer (score 1):

Переделанный вариант:
Имеем "драйвер" :

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise')
const DB_config = require('../config/db.config')
const db = mysql.createPool(DB_config);


module.exports =  db
```

И в файлах приложения подключаем его и используем:

```
const db = require('../utils/db.utils')


class authController {
   
    async getUsers(req, res) {
        try {
            const [rows, fields] = await db.execute(`SELECT count(*) AS count FROM users WHERE Email = 'test'`)            
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
            res.status(200).json(rows[0]['count'])
           
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = new authController()
```