# Как получить информацию из mysql динамически, на сервере Node.js с выводом в html, без php

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Переношу сайт с php сервера на ноду. В php нормально работает подключение с бд, это понятно) Но с нодой проблемы. Установил msql и mysql-loader, это мне даёт результатом получение данных из бд, но только на момент сборки проекта. При изменении Данных в базе они не подгружаются, я так понял потому что data приходит на этапе сборки и больше к серверу не достучишься.
Результатом хочу получить динамическое обновление этой dat`ы, чтобы не пересобирать проект при каждом изменении в бд

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp

Comment: вам нужно в приложении сделать api и динамическую подгрузку данных ajax-ом. mysql-loader выкинуть. или сделать [рендеринг страниц на стороне сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1220053/2659)

Answer (score 0):

Данный вопрос не возможно решить(возможно можно решить похожие, но не этот), как мне подсказали на хабре, ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226374/webpack-%D0%B8-mysql-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/1228503#1228503)