# Webpack и Mysql динамическое соединений

Tags: mysql, node.js, webpack

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но погуглил ещё и понял что ошибся, спросив как динамически соединить nodejs и mysql. Как я понял основная проблема именно в сборке вебпака.
Сейчас после сборки вебпаком проекта, я с помощью mysql-loader могу логировать в консоли браузера данные из mysql, но если я изменю данные в бд и обновлю страницу, то в браузере ничего не изменится, и только после пересборки проекта отобразятся изменения, что совсем не удобно.

P.s. ищу готовое решение, так как я не хочу заниматься бэкендом, осталось лишь динамически законектиться с бд и можно заниматься чистым фронтом, что мне и нужно.

P.s.s. Читал уже и про пулы и про сокеты, вот уже какой день бьюсь ничего не пойму, прошу, не посылайте учить мат часть, мне нужно лишь одно готовое решение и забить на бек

Comment: я [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223174/#comment2140877_1223174) вам. на каких технологиях вы пишете свой "чистый фронт"?

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось я пытался сделать либо то что пока не возможно, либо то что не нужно. Проблема в том, что я хотел запустить скрипты js как и скрипты php, но оказалось на хостинге все работает как то не так и нужно запускать отдельный сервер, а там нужен совсем иной билд